# Play multiple audio sounds in mobile devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, audio, mobile

I am working on building a game which has different sounds.

I am using the below for playing them

```
var jackpot_audio_file = document.getElementById('jackpot_sound');
jackpot_audio_file.play();
```

It works perfectly on desktop but not on mobile devices. Some play because I have a click then sound plays, but for the rest which do not need user to click anything didn't work.

I tried with simulated click with trigger('click') but it also didn't work.

Comment: here i am not seeing any jquery code

Comment: Sorry yes javascript.

Comment: does your game run in a browser? or is it compiled? what browser or compiler are you using? 

did you try on multiple devices or an emulator?

Comment: yes it runs in browser, simple js, html5. The issue is that most of the sounds play on specific cases without user click which is the reason that they dont work. The simulate click with javascript also dont work @Maher Fattouh.

Comment: Will it possible to have a popup for the user with Allow,disallow buttons and the "Allow" button will download all sounds then play properly on mobile @MaherFattouh?

Comment: this is definitely a browser related issue. Audio object is an object handled by browsers. I tried creating a JSFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/rbnhbuLr/1/ ) it worked perfectly on Chrome PC, but didn't play at all in Chrome Android but I can still play both sounds together by click the play control. but not on the default Samsung browser. once I play one it pauses the previous one. I think Audio object is not reliable for your case.

Comment: the allow button would be a bad user experience, and it wouldn't work anyway because most browser don't allow local loading local content for security reasons.

Comment: I know. I cant show the popup on every single audio which is not being triggered by user click. If that would be prompted just once it will be ok somehow @Maher Fattouh.

Comment: I don't think the source of the audio is the issue, rather the audio object itself and how browsers handle it differently. I'm trying something right now, will get back to you soon

Comment: OK I tried this Audio DOM object (https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/rbnhbuLr/1/) and pure Java new Audio (https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/rbnhbuLr/3/) and both failed on mobile. but I found this (http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/03/13/making-html5-audio-actually-work-on-mobile/) it might help. sorry I couldn't be any more of help

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I've faced the same issues and found a way around it.

As you may have realized, you can't trigger a sound to play by itself on mobile environments. For it to play, it is required a touch event by the user.

So, what I did the following:

1 - I declared all sounds I'm going to play beforehand

```
var sound1 = new Audio('file1.mp3');
var sound2 = new Audio('file1.mp3');
var sound3 = new Audio('file1.mp3');
```

2 - I created a screen with a button that the user MUST click in order to proceeed to the game:

```
<button onclick="proceeed()">proceeed</button>
```

3 - declared a function to be called by this button, that will set all audios volume to zero, play them all, pause them all, and proceed to the game:

```
function proceed() {
    sound1.volume = 0;
    sound2.volume = 0;
    sound3.volume = 0;

    sound1.play();
    sound1.pause();
    sound2.play();
    sound2.pause();
    sound3.play();
    sound3.pause();

    sound1.volume = 1;
    sound2.volume = 1;
    sound3.volume = 1;

    startGame();
}
```

This way all sounds are "played" with a touch event and loaded into memory. Next time in the application you want to play a sound, you just call

```
sound1.play();
```

and the sound will be played, even if there're other sounds being played.

Still we can't make it play automatically, but we can "trick" the user into provinding us the event we need so sounds are freely available for playing. It allows you to have a background theme and play sound effects on top of it.

You can check the result here:

http://thechase.besaba.com (open it on a mobile device).

The source code can be found at: https://github.com/Vinas/theChase.

Hope this was useful!

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed using Android/Chrome. Just place step 1 and 3 in a function that is activated by a click (ex. Start Button). If applicable this also works if variables are global. ex. ` window.sound1 = new Audio('file1.mp3'); `